# Form input max-width not working inside a flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a header with a couple of icons, a title, and a search box that animates the input field when I click on the search button. Everything works great except when I go to smaller screens. The intended effect I would like is that on a smaller screen the search field would expand all the way to the edge to hide the icon and title on the left, but I can't get the input field to accept the max-width property.

I have tried setting a fixed width on the search field, and messing around with the flex-basis and flex-shrink on the different containers, but nothing seems to work. I am open to simplifying the markup seeing as I have a flex within a flex within a flex... but it seemed to be the best way to get everything centered, responsive and spaced neatly.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #DDD;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

header {
  background-color: #AAA;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
}

.icon {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.search-field {
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 2rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 0;
}

.search-field:focus {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.search {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="flex-center">
    <div class="flex-left flex-center">
      <button class="icon"></button>
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right flex-center">
      <form class="search-form flex-center">
        <input id="search-field" class="search-field" type="search">
        <label class="icon" for="search-field"></label>
      </form>
      <button class="icon"></button>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

I am also open to vanilla JavaScript solutions if there is no other way to do this in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

To see the result you have to check from `600px` `viewport width` or below. And the `:has()` pseudo-class has limited browser support (it doesn't work in Firefox).

[Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas())

Necessary details are included with comments inside the codes.

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: #DDD;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: both;
}

header {
    background-color: #AAA;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.flex-center {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.icon {
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
}

.icon {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
}

.search-field {
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 2rem;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 0;
}

.search-field:focus {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

.search {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* new added codes ======================================================= */

/* You can set the screen width from when you want the input to cover the total left side */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    /* hiding the title and the icon when the input(search-field) is on focus in smaller screens */
    header:has(.search-field:focus) .flex-left{
        display: none;
    }

    /* setting the full width for the flex-right contents */
    header:has(.search-field:focus) .flex-right{
        width: 100%;
    }

    header:has(.search-field:focus) .flex-right form{
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* unsetting the max-width of the input so that it can take 100% of the width instead of the 300px max-width restriction */
    .search-field:focus {
        max-width: unset;
    }

    /* this height is depending upon the title */
    header:has(.search-field:focus){
        height: 5rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="flex-center">
          <div class="flex-left flex-center">
            <button class="icon"></button>
            <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-right flex-center">
            <form class="search-form flex-center">
              <input id="search-field" class="search-field" type="search">
              <label class="icon" for="search-field"></label>
            </form>
            <button class="icon"></button>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakibul for your help, I didn't know about the :has() pseudo class, but it seems I figured it out without having to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I removed display: flex from the header and positioned the left div with position: absolute to take it out of the flow of the document. This way I can expand the right flex box full width. This is the markup and css I ended up with. From here I can just add a media query to make it 100% of the width when the screen size gets small enough, and I avoid having to use the has: pseudo class.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #DDD;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

header {
  background-color: #AAA;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.left {
  left: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.icon {
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
}

.search-btn {
  background-color: blue;
}

.search-field {
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  height: 2rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 0;
}

.search-field:focus {
  width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .search-field:focus {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="left flex-center">
      <button class="icon"></button>
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="right flex-center">
      <input id="search-field" class="search-field" type="search">
      <label class="icon search-btn" for="search-field"></label>
      <button class="icon"></button>
    </form>
  </header>
</div>
```